# Issue with Reading VB.Net CSV Files into List, Missing Half of the Values

Tags: string, vb.net, list, visual-studio, csv

I have been attempting to read in CSV files containing numeric data consisting of 1000 rows for each of the 19 columns within the files. I have been succesful with my current code in reading each column in an individual file and adding the values to a list of decimals but I am receiving an interesting user error that I cannot seem to figure out. The output list only adds half of the values from the CSV file such that halving the row range specified in the second for loop seems to halve the amount of outputted values (ie. 1000 rows specified in the for loop results in 500 values in the outcome list, 500 rows results in 250 values in the outcome list). The code is called from a function with the file path as an argument represented by filePath:

'''

```
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) = False Then 'What to do if the file does not exist at the specified path
        Throw New Exception("File Not Found: " & filePath) 'Error message if file does not exist
    ElseIf My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filePath) = True Then 'What to do if the file does exist at the specified path
        Dim fileData = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        Dim fileColumnCount = (fileData.First.Split(","c).Length) - 1
        Dim fileRowCount = fileData.Length
        Dim column As Integer
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim currentColumn As New List(Of Decimal)
        column = 0
        For column = 0 To fileColumnCount
            row = 0
            currentColumn.Clear()
            For row = 0 To (fileRowCount - 1)
                Dim placeholder As String = fileData(row)
                Dim currentLine() As String = placeholder.Split(",")
                Dim lineList As List(Of String) = currentLine.ToList()
                Dim value_dec As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(lineList(column))
                currentColumn.Add(value_dec)
                row += 1
            Next
            column += 1
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

'''

When I check currentColumn (the output list for an individual column within the CSV file) after running the program with a breakpoint prior to restarting the first for loop so that only the first column is checked, only the first half of the values are added. Even though row is equal to 1000 indicating that each row value has been parsed, I am always missing half of the data. Any thoughts or advice? Thank you.

Edit: After some more testing, it seems that evenly spaced values are not being included in the output dataset. Still no luck fixing the issue.

Comment: When you parse CSV files, you usually loop the rows and, for each row, extract the values of its Fields. Not the other way around. I suggest to use, at least, the [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) class to parse a CSV file or, probably better, [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). -- When asking for assistance in parsing text, you should always provide a meaningful sample of that text. Better also add the CultureInfo / language in use.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

This little snippet should do it all

```
For each row in split(csvfiletext, environment.newline)
    dim listviewitem as new listviewitem
    For each column in split(row, ",")
      listviewitem.subitems.add(column)
    Next
    Listview1.items.add(listviewitem)
next
```

It splits the file content on Rows, and then on columns. And adds ListViewItems to a ListView while it loops trough the text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make row add 1 in the loop.

```
            For row = 0 To (fileRowCount - 1)
                ...
                row += 1
            Next
```

Delete `row += 1`:

```
            For row = 0 To (fileRowCount - 1)
                Dim placeholder As String = fileData(row)
                Dim currentLine() As String = placeholder.Split(",")
                Dim lineList As List(Of String) = currentLine.ToList()
                Dim value_dec As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(lineList(column))
                currentColumn.Add(value_dec)
            Next
```